# Kivy build fails on windows 10

Tags: python, kivy

Trying to setup kivy on windows 10 using python 3.6 the issue is as you can see below.

```
b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

This is the only problem the process continues on and attempts to build but fails, I tried to post the full terminal output here but it exceeded the site's character limit lol. Aside from it saying windows doesn't recognize the command I really don't understand the issue or know how to fix it.

```
C:\Users\suroh>python -m pip install kivy
Collecting kivy
Using cached kivy-1.9.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4 in c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from kivy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from Kivy-Garden>=0.1.4->kivy)
Building wheels for collected packages: kivy
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for kivy ... error
Complete output from command C:\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\suroh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip- build-8971r5gl\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\suroh\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp18y3lc72pip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
Using distutils

Detected Cython version 0.23
User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
Windows platform detected, force GLEW usage.
Using this graphics system: OpenGL
WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

WARNING: A problem occured while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for kivy
Running setup.py clean for kivy
Failed to build kivy
Installing collected packages: kivy
Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
Complete output from command C:\Python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\suroh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-8971r5gl\\kivy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\suroh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-jyo4b4xe-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
```

Any idea what the issue is and if so how can I fix it? Aside from downgrading to python 2 and trying that way.

Comment: No stable releases for 3.5 nor 3.6 for now. Check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivy

Comment: My apologies I didn't know that but it makes sense, thank you for the reply. Also I don't mean to impose but could you perhaps put this in the form of an answer so I can mark it as solved, if not I understand and again thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now (Kivy 1.9.1) there are no releases for Python 3.5 and higher (both 32 and 64bit). You can check it at [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kivy), which is where the wheels are stored.

You can however use [nightly wheels](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#nightly-wheel-installation). Those are pretty much more stable than the current stable as the new release is kind of close. :)

Comment: I have running projects in production using python3.5